# Can you bind two functions to button.when_pressed in python gpiozero?

Tags: python, gpiozero

I am trying to bind two functions to a button, so for example I want to toggle a buzzer and LED with a single button. Is there a way to attach two functions to the same button or can a button only do a single thing at once?

For example:

```
button.when_pressed = led.toggle && buzzer.toggle
```

Comment: You can only bind one function - but that function can call as many other functions as it likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 solutions. Just merge the two functions into a `single function`, then call up that single function with the button, or alternatively using a `lambda`

**SOLUTION N.1**

```
def ledtoggle_buzzertoggle():
    led.toggle()
    buzzer.toggle()

button.when_pressed = ledtoggle_buzzertoggle
```

**SOLUTION N.2**

You can also use `lambda`

```
button.when_pressed = lambda:[led.toggle(), buzzer.toggle()] #or without square brackets
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind to a function that calls both functions:

```
def toggle_led_and_buzzer():
    led.toggle()
    buzzer.toggle()

button.when_pressed = toggle_led_and_buzzer
```